# Does JDBC have a method to get table and column statistics?

Tags: jdbc, statistics

Does JDBC support retrieving table and column statistics (like NUM_DISTINCT) or do i have to directly access the statistics table for each DB vendor ? 
(e.g., for Oracle, 
"select column_name, num_distinct, density from dba_tab_col_statistics where table_name='myTable'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC is database agnostic, and doesn't define much in terms of statistics. The only type of table-related statistics currently defined in JDBC are part of `DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo`, and they are largely optional. I'm not sure which drivers implement it, and to what extent.

See [`DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,boolean,boolean)), specifically for `TYPE` `tableIndexStatistic`:

> 11. `CARDINALITY` `long` => When `TYPE` is `tableIndexStatistic`, then this is the number of rows in the table; otherwise, it is the number
>       of unique values in the index.
> 12. `PAGES` `long` => When `TYPE` is `tableIndexStatistic` then this is the number of pages used for the table, otherwise it is the number
>       of pages used for the current index.

Even if the driver for your database supports `tableIndexStatistic`, you're probably better off using the database specific features for obtaining statistics though, as they are more likely to be documented, have a wider range of options, and more people are aware of the meaning and interpretation.

Although I'm a member of the JDBC Expert Group, I'm not aware of the historic reasons for this absence (or if it even ever came up before I joined), but if I had to theorize, I think this is likely because the types and availability of statistics vary a lot between databases.

This diversity makes it hard to standardize on an API that is still usable for both sides (little to no statistics and a wide variety of statistics). Nothing is more frustrating than to have an extensive (and maybe complex) API, to just get nothing out of it because it isn't supported for your database. In a similar vein, it can be quite frustrating to have a database with a lot of statistics, but you can't access some of it because it just doesn't fit with the standard API.